# Extracting words from txt file using python

Tags: python, regex, text, nltk

I want to extract all the words that are between single quotation marks from a text file. The text file looks like this:

```
u'MMA': 10,
=u'acrylic'= : 19,
== u'acting lessons': 2,
=u'aerobic': 141,
=u'alto': 2= 4,
=u&#= 39;art therapy': 4,
=u'ballet': 939,
=u'ballroom'= ;: 234,
= =u'banjo': 38,
```

And ideally, my output would look lie this:

```
MMA,
acrylic,
acting lessons,
...
```

From browsing posts, it seems like I should use some combination of NLTK / regex for python to accomplish this. I've tried the following:

```
import re

file = open('artsplus_categories.txt', 'r').readlines()

for line in file:
    list = re.search('^''$', file)

file.close()
```

And get the following error:

```
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 142, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

I think the error might be caused by how I'm looking for the pattern.  My logic is that I search for everything inside of the '....'.

What's tripping up re.py?

Thanks!

### --------------------------------

Following Ashwini's comment:

```
import re

file = open('artsplus_categories.txt', 'r').readlines()

for line in file:
    list = re.search('^''$', line)

print list

#file.close()
```

But the output contains nothing:

```
Samuel-Finegolds-MacBook-Pro:~ samuelfinegold$ /var/folders/jv/9_sy0bn10mbdft1bk9t14qz40000gn/T/Cleanup\ At\ Startup/artsplus_categories_clean-393952531.278.py.command ; exit;
None
logout
```

---

---

@Rasco: here's the error I'm getting:

```
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 177, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
logout
```

I'm using this code:

```
file2 = open('artsplus_categories.txt', 'r').readlines()
list = re.findall("'[^']*'", file2)
for x in list:
    print (x)
```

Comment: Read the error, that's line 142 in re.py, not your text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing the `line` to the regex you actually passed it the whole list(file). You should pass `line` to `re.search` not `file`.

```
for line in file:
    lis = re.search('^''$', line) # line not file
```

Don't use `list`, `file` as variable names. They are built-in functions.

**Update:**

```
with open('artsplus_categories.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print re.search(r"'(.*)'", line).group(1)
...         
MMA
acrylic
acting lessons
aerobic
alto
art therapy
ballet
ballroom
banjo
```

Comment: I see! Thank you for that catch. I'm trying to amend the code now to get the list of words, but when I run the code with your edit, my list is empty.

Comment: @goldisfine Instead if printing `file` you're printing `list`, `file` list is not empty.And your regex is also incorrect.

Comment: @goldisfine Try my updated code. And `=u&#= 39;art therapy': 4,` line is seem to be missing opening quote. Do you want to print that line?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code example:

```
import re

file =  """u'MMA': 10,
        =u'acrylic'= : 19,
        == u'acting lessons': 2,
        =u'aerobic': 141,
        =u'alto': 2= 4,
        =u&#= 39;art therapy': 4,
        =u'ballet': 939,
        =u'ballroom'= ;: 234,
        = =u'banjo': 38,"""

list = re.findall("'[^']*'", file)
for x in list:
    print (x)
```

It shows the correct values. Keep in mind that one of the values in your example doesn't open the quote correctly, so the matches get broken there.

Comment: Hmmm...I tried import re

'file = open('artsplus_categories.txt', 'r').readlines()

list = re.findall("'[^']*'", file)

print list' and that led to this: '  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 177, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer'

Comment: Sorry, used Python syntax (instead of Python 3). It should be fine now (fixed the `print(x)` line).

Comment: I cannot follow the code you just put. Please put it in the question so I can see it correctly :)