# Extracting a word from text file using Python

Tags: python, words

Still quite new to this whole Python thing.  Here's what I'm trying to do:

[Extracting words from txt file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323801/extracting-words-from-txt-file-using-python)

SORT of like that, but instead of taking out words between single quotes, I need to take words out of double quotes FOLLOWING a certain word.

Right now, I have the script scraping a website and saving the HTML.  Works great.  No problem.
Then I have BeautifulSoup arranging the HTML and searching for all the tables in the page which the data I need is in.
Below is an example of one of the table lines:

```
<td style="background-color:red;w ...blahblahblah... margin:0px;background:none" title="Bland NB" type="button" value="TRX"/>
```

BeautifulSoup arranges all the HTML as one table line per line (if that makes sense) and I have a search using regex to only pull out the table lines that have "background-color:red" in them as the red ones are the only ones I care about getting the titles of. I just need the script to go through line by line (there are ~350 lines just like above but with different titles) and take out what's in quotes right after 'title=' and save all of it to a text file one "title=" entry per line if you know what I mean...

I think BeautifulSoup might be able to do it.  I've been wrestling with partition and strip functions but can't get them to do what I want them to do.  I also think I might be able to use a regex to do it but that's a can o' worms in and of itself.

I'm so close!  Any help greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!!

**EDIT**

I can't post more of the code as it contains company IPs and info that I can't put out in the wild.  Sorry.

--Brent

Comment: Can you post what you have so far?

Comment: what do you expect from the html you posted?

Comment: That's an edited line that I included just to illustrate what it is that I'm actually trying to get out of the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
html = """
<td style="background-color:red;w ...blahblahblah... margin:0px;background:none" title="Bland NB" type="button" value="TRX"/>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

if "background-color:red" in td.get("style"):
    print soup.td.get("title")
    Bland NB
```

To put it all together:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

all_tds = soup.findAll("td")

with open("out.txt","a+") as f:
    for td in all_tds:
        if "background-color:red" in soup.td.get("style"):
            f.write(soup.td.get("title")+"\n")
```

Comment: It's looking like this will do the trick, good Sir.  I'm in the process of fitting it into the rest of the code and whatnot but it looks like it should work perfectly.  Thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome, you will have to tweak it a bit to suit your own code but it should work fine.

Comment: I am in the the tweakage process right now.  that "soup.td.get()" was what I was looking for.  Thanks again EVERYONE who helped!  Greatly appreciated!